# Error on using union clause in cte sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm trying to do following but getting an max recursive error. Can someone please help?

Sample code to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
DECLARE @SecurityMaster AS TABLE
(
    ID              INT,
    SecurityAlias   INT,
    LegNumber       INT
)

INSERT INTO @SecurityMaster
SELECT 12829, 3030106, NULL 
UNION ALL
SELECT 12829, 3030107, 1

SELECT * FROM @SecurityMaster;

WITH CTE1 (ID, SecurityAlias, LegNumber)
AS
(
    SELECT S.ID, S.SecurityAlias, S.LegNumber
    FROM @SecurityMaster S 
    WHERE S.LegNumber IS NOT NULL

    UNION ALL

    select s.ID, s.SecurityAlias, s.LegNumber
    from @SecurityMaster S inner join CTE1 c on s.ID = c.ID
    where s.LegNumber is NULL
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE1;
```

Result I'm expecting:

```
ID          SecurityAlias       LegNumber
-----------------------------------------
12829       3030107             1
12829       3030106             NULL
```

Comment: Your desired output is exactly the same as the data in your table variable.

Comment: My real data set is complex so I tried to create a sample data set. Is it possible to get the result?

Comment: You're sample code fails to demonstrate what you are really trying to do. Why are you using a recursive CTE in the first place? You are simply joining on the same table column, so what is the reason behind using recursion?

Comment: The error I'm getting is "Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion."

Comment: I would like to understand why it's giving that error and how to get the result

Comment: Your `CTE` keeps joining and joining the same records over and over again. There is not exit condition.

Comment: Normally these kind of CTEs are used to produce a tree-like structrure. In this case `JOIN` is performed using parent / child ids, which is clearly not the case here.

Comment: Can you please recommend an alternative to my query?

Comment: Well I could have if I really knew what you are trying to achieve ...

Comment: I get that your real data is complex but this is so simplified there is nothing here. Your query "SELECT * FROM @SecurityMaster;" returns your desired output.

Comment: In my real life dataset I’m joining multiple tables with where conditions to @SecurityMaster table and the record with NULL Legnumber doesn’t comeup (Every record which come up in this resultset has a record with NULL Legnumber in @SecurityMaster). Without placing the entire where clauses again to query, I want to retrieve NULL Leg records from the ID’s I’m getting from first query.

Answer (score 0):

Your questionis difficult to understand, but will this work for you?

```
select s.ID, s.SecurityAlias, s.LegNumber
from @SecurityMaster S
where s.LegNumber is NULL
And s.id in (SELECT f.ID
FROM @SecurityMaster f
WHERE f.LegNumber IS NOT NULL)
```